# Does a passive LCD's screen have 1 pin to 1 segment?

Tags: lcd

I'm very green in electronic engineering. But I have a 1997 Yamaha AN1X synth with a custom LCD screen that is only half operating and was thinking of making a replacement from todays parts with some controller to translate the information coming from the board. But I see that today's displays are operated with a square pulse and is not trivial.

The LCD has probably 50 tracks on the glass edge. Do these passive displays also have square wave controller pulses to operate ?

Comment: I think it's usually a matrix. Like a grid. To drive a segment, you drive that row and that column at the same time. Are you sure the LCD is unfixable though? It could just be a bad connection.

Comment: You might find the EEVBlog (Dave Jones) video series on LCD helpful, whether you try to repair or replace it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mo4_5vG8bbU

Comment: I tried to fix it by cleaning the contacts. that did not work terribly well though. I lost a few more segments during the process. But the rubber edge connectors are also not well secured as they rely on the front casing to compress the contacts.  I also did not poke at it with a meter. A scope would be a nice thing to have at this point :-)

Comment: make sure that you clean the rubber edge connector really well .... google `zebra strip` ... rub the contacts with plain printer paper ... paper is slightly abrasive and it will polish contacts